# Recyclerview keep same position like listview

Tags: android, listview

```
final ListView accountDetailsList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
/*int index = accountDetailsList.getFirstVisiblePosition() + nm.size();
View v = accountDetailsList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - accountDetailsList.getPaddingTop());
accountDetailsList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);*/
int index = accountDetailsList.getFirstVisiblePosition() + nm.size();
View v = accountDetailsList.getChildAt(accountDetailsList.getHeaderViewsCount());
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// this.adapter.AddRangeToTop(nm);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I would like to know what is the equivalent of that for recyclerview, i m loading data at first.and i like to keep my position. so my position is5th, i loaded 10 more data..i want it to go to position 15. whats equivalent of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do: `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);` or `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`